# json / jq : multi-level grouping of sub-elements in an array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

i'm writing a script that needs to parse incoming json into line-by-line data, taking information from the json at multiple different levels. i'm using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) to parse the data.

the incoming json is an array of 'tasks'. each task [i.e. each element of the array] is an object that looks like this :

```
{
  "inputData": {
    "transfers": [
      {
        "source": {
          "directory": "/path/to/source",
          "filename": "somefile.mp3"
        },
        "target": {
          "directory": "/path/to/target",
          "filename": "somefile.mp3"
        }
      },
      {
        "source": {
          "content": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delivery>content description</delivery>",
          "encoding": "UTF-8"
        },
        "target": {
          "directory": "/path/to/target",
          "filename": "somefile.xml"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "outputData": {
    "transferDuration": "00:00:37:10",
    "transferLength": 187813298,
  },
  "updateDate": "2020-02-21T14:37:18.329Z",
  "updateUser": "bob"
}
```

i want to read all of the tasks and, for each one, output a single line composed of the following fields :

```
task[n].inputData.transfers[].target.filename, task[n].outputData.transferLength, task[n].updateDate
```

i've got my filter chain to where it will choose the appropriate fields correctly, even to where it will pick the 'correct' single entry from amongst the multiple entries in the `task[].inputData.transfers[]` array, but when i try to get the output of more than a single element, the chain iterates over the array three times, and i get

```
task[0].inputData.transfers[].target.filename
task[1].inputData.transfers[].target.filename
task[2].inputData.transfers[].target.filename
... 
task[n].inputData.transfers[].target.filename
```

then the results of the `outputData.transferLength` field for all elements,
then the results of the `updateDate` field for all elements.

here is my filter chain :

```
'(.tasks[].inputData.transfers[] | select(.target.filename | match("[Xx][Mm][Ll]$")).target.filename), .tasks[].outputData.transferLength, .tasks[].updateDate'
```

i'm thinking there must be some efficient way to group all of these multi-level elements together for each element of the array ; something like a '**with ...**' clause, like `with tasks[] : blablabla`, but can't figure out how to do it. can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the answer. the trick was to pipe the `.tasks[]` into an expression where the parens were placed around the field elements as a group, which apparently will apply whatever is inside the parens to each element of the array individually, in sequence. then using @dmitry example as a guide, i also placed the elements inside right and left brackets to recreate array elements that i could then select, which could then be output onto 1 line each with `| @csv`. so the final chain that worked for me is :

```
.task[] | ([.inputData.transfers[].target.filename, .outputData.transferLength, .updateDate]) | [(.[0],.[2],.[3])] | @csv'
```

unfortunately i couldn't get `match()` to work in this invocation, nor `sub()` ; each of these caused jq to offer a useless error message just before it dumped core.

many thanks to the people who replied.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON example contained a superfluous `,` that `jq` won't accept.

Your example filter chain appears to operate on `.tasks[]` even though the example appears to be only a single task. So it is not possible to rewrite what you have got into a functioning state. So rather than provide an exact answer to an inexact question, here is the first of the three parts of your filter chain revised:

```
.inputData.transfers | map(select(.target.filename | match("xml$"; "i")))
```

See [this jqplay snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/C3UvyrF5hQ).

Rather than write `[ .xs[] | select(p) ]`, just write `.xs | map(select(p))`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. sorry, english is not my native language. i will try to restate. my example has _one_ element of an array. i need all 3 fields from _each_ array element on the same line. the commas are required to get the output of 3 separate parts of each element. your example does provide some of the same information as mine did for the 1st field, but doesn't select the part i need, and i still get the first field from all of the elements, then the 2nd field from all of the elements, then the 3rd field from all of the elements, rather than the 3 fields from the 1st element, etc

Comment: @davidfurst: "all 3 fields from each array element on the same line": What do you mean by "on the same line"? The result of the query I produced is not a *line*, but a *list of objects*. By "a line" I'd assume maybe a string. Could you provide an example of the output you expect? Maybe that will be easier to decipher than your explanation. Try and avoid errors in the example. StackOverflow isn't a very good medium for multiple iterations forth-and-back, so please try and state your question concisely the first time. :-) How to embed the 2nd and 3rd fields still isn't clear to me.

Comment: sure. what i mean is something like this :<br><br>
        somefile.xml 472647 2020-02-24T13:04:56.815Z
<br><br>
here is 1 line for 1 element of the n-element array. supposing there are 15 elements in the incoming json, then i would get 15 lines in the resulting output. what i am getting now is 45 lines of output -- 15 lines of the first field, then 15 lines of the second field, then 15 lines of the third field.

Comment: i want this jqplay output https://jqplay.org/s/c049G4bs5x to appear on one line instead of 3.

Comment: @Dmitry many thanks !  that does put the output on one line, and thanks to you i learned a good way to do that. there is still the problem that when the input array has _multiple elements_, the result is still output as field 1 from all elements, followed by field 2 from all elements, followed by field 3 from all elements, rather than fields 1,2,3 from the first element, then fields 1,2,3 from the second, etc. i will still keep trying other approaches combined with your approach to put the results of each element on one line,